# Joomla 4.0.3 relaunches the installer even after completing installation

Tags: joomla

I can't get past installer for Joomla 4.0.3 even after installation. I checked the database was successfully installed with 26 tables but when I try to go home it relaunches the installer - see the attached picture below:
[image]

Comment: Please ask all of your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Is the installation folder deleted on your server?